# NSNotification is not posting when posted from swift closures

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotifications

This is the observer I have added,

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "XYZ"), object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] (notification) -> Void in
                // self.somemethods()
            }
```

This where I post notification,

```
self.fetchData({ (data) -> Void in
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "XYZ"), object: nil)
               //use data
            }, failure: { (error) -> Void in
            })
```

When I post this the observer methods are not called. I have not removed the observer, also I ensured that notification is posted from main thread. Please help.

Comment: try posting it in MainThread, I don't know if your closure return in mainThread

Comment: Are you sure when notification posted your viewcontroller is in memory ?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I did it inspite of knowing that the closure gets executed in main thread. Still its not observed. The thing is the "default" text is pink in color when the whole line " NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "XYZ"), object: nil)" put inside closure. Else it will be showed in voilet color like as "NotificationCenter" text. This sounds silly. But I dunno if the difference makes sense.

Comment: Yes @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: sure fetchData callback is executed

Comment: Remove [weak self] and access any property inside if crashed then it's deallocated

Comment: also check if you remove observer in viewDidDisappear or any where

Comment: I have not removed observer, object is in memory and notification is posted i have checked

Comment: Where do you have the observer code and the fetchData code?